# Qt build error: "WARNING: TARGET is empty" and "make: nothing to be done for "first""

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi

I recently installed qt5 on Raspbian. I'm trying to compile [this package](https://github.com/groupgets/LeptonModule/tree/master/software/raspberrypi_qt) so I ran`qmake && make`. I get these errors:

```
WARNING: TARGET is empty
make: nothing to be done for 'first'
```

Before having qt5 (and qt-creator), I can compile the code seamlessly with qt4 installed in my raspberry pi. So I think it could be some incompatibility issue with qt5. How can I build this code without having to revert back to qt4?

*Note: I'm new with Qt and Linux.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got no errors, just one warning message from qmake and one message from make. Qt5 qmake doesn't substitute project file name (without extension .pro) for the target file name (specified by the TARGET variable), and Qt4 qmake really does it. You should specify target file name in the project file raspberrypi_qt.pro:

```
TARGET = raspberrypi_qt
```

Comment: I see now, Thanks for your time and attention bro.